# vscode launch.json react-native & Haxe

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, launcher

I started moving from coding directly react-native project with Haxe.
Therefore the folder-structure has changed, that the react-native project files are in a subfolder of the current project.

When i do want to use the `launch.json` the output tells me (correctly) that there is no react-native npm package installed at root.
my `launch.json` looks like this now (tried to add rn-project-name) as a subfolder

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/rn-project-name/.launch/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "iPhone 5s",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/rn-project-name/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```

Has anyone ever had to solve something like this?

(I somehow do not understand how the `launch.json` sets up all neccessary file references)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working. Just edit `.vscode/settings.json` adding the project root path:

```json
{
    ... 

    "react-native-tools": {
        "projectRoot": "path-to-your-rn-project"
    }
}
```